# ssh keys works for root works on two clients to same server, but not for another user

Tags: ssh, remote-access, ssh-keys

My question is simple. I have 2 clients (A and B). Both clients are OSX (mac). I configured ssh keys to connect passwordless to the same server (Debian Server). User root (the user which I use for authenticate to Debian server) works smooth from client A and B (it can scp and SFTP without password promtp). User temp (this a common user, that I need to use for upload/download content to SFTP. It doesn't have home directory, neither shell access) works from client A to server but not from client B.

On client B, performing ssh -v to server, shows that on both cases (authentication session for user root and for user temp), client B session offers the same RSA key with both users (root and temp), but server accepts user root, but not accepts with user temp.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Please be strict and explain ([edit]) what "user root" and "user temp" mean for you. It can be local users are `A` and `B`, while `root` and `temp` are users *on the server only*. Or maybe A and B are separate machines and there are `root` and `temp` users on A and (separately) on B and (separately) on the server. So 6 in total. I want to avoid confusion when I say e.g. "add `B`'s public key to `temp`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server" and it makes no sense for you because *maybe* `B` is not a user and `B`'s key is ill-defined (as opposed to `temp@B`'s key or `root@B`'s key).

Comment: Edited.. I hope now is more clear. Thanks

Comment: if you are into checking logs then be aware that there is a server log too that can be more useful than the client side log

Comment: The users have to be server side. Any client side "users" are irrelevant. And ssh with user@ip so it doesn't take the name of the client user. You need a user called "temp" on the server, if you want to log in with ssh as a user called temp.

Comment: Also, on the server, each user on the server has its own authorized_keys file, because that file is per profile. hence `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`  (~/ would be the home directory which differs from user to user)

Comment: ok Thanks. The point is server is the same in all situations. Temp user doesn't have home directory (doesn't have access to shell, only SFTP). I was not able to find the ./ssh/authorized_keys files.

Comment: Check the global `sshd_config` (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), maybe it specifies different location for `authorized_keys`. See `man 5 sshd_config` where it describes the `AuthorizedKeysFile` keyword. Possibly this is in use.

Comment: Hi Kamil for the advise. Nothing related to authorized_keys on this file. Really weird since it depends on the client connection, not on the user used for the connection. maybe I need to access to authorized keys manually?